# Perl CGI param or Vars, can I filter the list

Tags: perl, cgi, hidden, parameters, variables

I need to get back a list of either field names, or a hash, but I don't want hidden fields included? Possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "hidden" - can you give an example?

Comment: an html field with a hidden attribute such as <input type="hidden" name="myhiddenfield1" value="1">

Comment: If you have control over naming those hidden fields and you include "hidden" in those names, why not `my @names = grep !/hidden/, $query->param`?  This, however, gets only POST parameters.

Comment: Yes that would be a nightmare to go thru the CGI and find all those places, then of course have to remove the hidden's from them afterwards.. Thanks though I may have to bite the bullet.. I wish there was more DOM stuff available with $CGI.. We may end up trying to do this in JS instead...

Comment: There seems to be some serious misunderstanding of what CGI is. It's a communication protocol used by web servers to forward requests to child processes. It has nothing to do with HTML, so "DOM stuff" cannot possibly be added.

Comment: JS could collect such info on form submit, and pass it as additional parameter.

Answer (score 2):

No information about the type a field is will be sent by the browser, so there is no way to do this automatically.

You need to provide the data yourself, possibly as an array or hash in the Perl program.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you need a list of the fields from the HTML form except 'hidden' form fields.
You can even collect list of this fields manually your from and 'grep' them from the parameter list.

For example:

```
use CGI;

...    

my @hidden_fields = qw/field1 field2 field3/;
my $grep_fields = join '|', @hidden_fields;

...

my @fields = grep { !/\b($grep_fields)\b/ } $query->param();
```